# Angular calculation not updating in view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am creating a small application that calculates distance between two points. The console.log outputs the calculation correctly, but not the angular portion in the view. Only after a click or a second selection. I've setup two select fields (with separate ng-models) that are filled with information out of a JSON file. I've searched the internet extensively, but can't find an answer. Hopefully somebody can help me with this... :) This is my code:

```
var app = angular.module('calculateApp', []);
app.controller('calculateController', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('json/stops.json')
        .then(function(item){
        $scope.stations = item.data;
        $scope.station1 = false;
        $scope.station2 = false;
        // Watch and calculate
        $scope.$watch( 
            function( $scope ) {
                function distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
                  var R = 6371;
                  var a = 
                     0.5 - Math.cos((lat2 - lat1) * Math.PI / 180)/2 + 
                     Math.cos(lat1 * Math.PI / 180) * Math.cos(lat2 * Math.PI / 180) * 
                     (1 - Math.cos((lon2 - lon1) * Math.PI / 180))/2;
                  return R * 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a));
                }
                console.log(distance($scope.station1.stop_lat, $scope.station1.stop_lon, $scope.station2.stop_lat, $scope.station2.stop_lon));
                $scope.calculated = distance($scope.station1.stop_lat, $scope.station1.stop_lon, $scope.station2.stop_lat, $scope.station2.stop_lon);
            }
        );
        // end calculate
    });
});
```

I use this in my HTML file:

Total distance is: {{calculated}}

Answer (score 0):

First of all in a watch you dont need to send the scope into the function
you can however send newValue, oldValue  for those.

I think by removing the $scope from the watch function it is solved

edit:

i now see you want to watch the scope but then you dont need a function $scope

look at [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)
i think it will help you.

And i am not sure if you can watch the whole scope you should select the thing you need to watch.

Comment: Thank you :) I'll look into it. In the meantime i sort of fixed it, by using ng-show (it updates automatically then)

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding $scope.$apply at the end of your calculation.

Regards

Ian

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime i sort of fixed it, by using ng-show (it updates automatically then)